# My scrollViewDidScroll function is not receiving calls

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to check if a user is scrolling up and down on my app but it's not calling my `scrollViewDidScroll` method

Any ideas why it's not printing `received scroll` when I scroll up and down on the app?

```
import UIKit

class CreateAccount: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewer: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var reenterPasswordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("received scroll")
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't set the scrollview's delegate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the scrollview delegate. Whenever you implement a delegate method you need tell it what controller to use, usually it will be `self`. It's caught me out a few times.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.   
    scrollViewer.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Yep, sure enough that was it! Thanks! Is there anywhere I can read more about this? Like in the rare event I have two scrolling sections on the screen, how would I differentiate the two?

Comment: To be honest I don't know the answer to that one, I'd try something like `scrollView1.delegate = self` and `scrollView2 delegate = self`, I'd give each a different tag and check for that in the `scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)` by calling `scrollView.tag`. They should both call the same function.

Comment: Keep 2 property references to the `UIScrollView` instances. When the delegate function is called, the `UIScrollView` instance is passed in. Just do a simple `==` comparison to see which instance it is.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set delegate of scrollview also don't use tag to differentiate 2 scrollview instead of that create 2 outlets of scrollview and use that in `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods like this.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == scrollView1 {
         print("received scrollview 1")
    }
    else if scrollView == scrollView2 {
         print("received scrollview 2")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nirav! That's awesome, never knew you could do that.

Answer (score 3):

Delegate are given properly even if your scrollview delegate method not calling then please check you delegate method which you have added for scrollview, this **may give warning** due to using old swift version scrollview delegate with swift 4.0

Please correct it with below if this is the case:

**Old Method:**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
}
```

**New Method:**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `.delegate = self` as *Sarcoma* suggests, **or:**

**CTRL drag from scrollView** in storyboard onto the File Owner (it is located in the view hierarchy list, actually it is right by the yellow circle icon by the name of your controller: **[O] Create Account** and choose

- delegate